# ACH payments Stripe

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, payment

Until now I was using automatic_payments_on in my javascript/php integration for Stripe. It auto creates payment methods i enabled in Stripe dashboard and they look pretty cool. Due to my personal processing reasons I want to separate card and ach us payments.

before my code looked like this (automatic payments on)

```
elements = stripe.elements({
clientSecret: data.client_secret
});
const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
```

Since I want to separately create elements for card and ach payment, If I use [StripeAPI method for collecting](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API). Will this auto generate design to match one from paymentElement (when using automatic payments on), where user can pick bank and everything looks nice? How to seperate it but keep the same design?

I tried this to separate :

```
createACHPElement(clientSecret) {
    const elements = this.stripe.elements({
        clientSecret: clientSecret
    });

    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', {
        paymentMethodTypes: ['ach_credit_transfer']
    });

    paymentElement.mount("#ach-element");
    return paymentElement;
}
```

But it's generating me and mounting a CARD payment. In php backend i'm not doing anything "crazy", just creating a normal payment intent. note: i dont want to use any 3rd party like plaid. Maybe i'm just missing something obvious...

Comment: The Payment Element displays the payment methods based off the PaymentIntent. If you only want to accept ACH debit payments, you need to create the PaymentIntent with payment_method_types[]=us_bank_account - see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API#web-create-payment-intent for an example